# how is these two different codes return the same result

Tags: javascript

I have seen this question in on of the JS Quizes. Not able to understand how, How does these two different codes return the same result. I read about JS Hoisting but unable to understand this.

```js
function bar(){
return foo;
function foo(){}
var foo='11'
}

bar()
```

```js
function bar(){
return foo;
var foo='11'
function foo(){}
}
bar()
```

Comment: Just don't use an identifier twice ... :)

Comment: When the body of a function is evaluated, all variable and function declarations are "collected". For every variable declaration, and entry is created in the new scope (and initialized to `undefined` in case of `var`). For every function declaration, the function is evaluated and set in the scope. Function declarations are set "last" so they overwrite any existing variable entry that might exist.